# Do super hot peppers blister as they ripen?

Tags: peppers

Do super hot peppers like the [Big Black Mama](http://thehotpepper.com/topic/55936-big-black-mama/) and [Carolina Reaper](http://www.instructables.com/id/Growing-the-Carolina-Reaper/) blister as they ripen?

Comment: I'm migrating this to our gardening site. I've also removed the general question - these sites tend to like specific questions. If there are related things you want to know about growing these peppers, by all means edit them in!

Comment: What do you mean by blister? Can you give us an example of a pepper or other fruit that does blister? Why did you think they might blister?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I back up Ljk2000's answer as it's never happened to me either. Even under hot sun, all I *might* see would be some sunscald (the plant equivalent of a sunburn).

The two peppers you linked to aren't *blistered* as they might look but are instead **bumpy** as that's the way they develope as hybrids. If they were blistered, you'd expect the skin to be raised from the flesh on the blisters. They're not. Skin and flesh are both bumpy as they were meant to be. Other peppers might be as hot (I didn't check out their 'heat rating') but they could be either smooth, bumpy or slightly ridged depending on the hybrids' DNA.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the answers. The reason I ask is because I thought I was growing a few big black mama plants but the pods are smooth and orange and don't have that crazy bumpy look. I was wondering if that comes as they ripen. I'm starting to think I got the wrong seeds... these look and smell like orange habaneros. Lol

Comment: By the way thanks for getting me to the right forum. I'm new to this and haven't figured it out just yet.

Comment: @BigOPepperCompany Live and learn my friend, its better to ask. No matter what question. Its nice to have a new member, and I forgot to say, Welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

I will simply tell you from my years of growing and learning with growing. I have grown many different types of hot peppers. Such as habanero, jalapeno, etc. Through out all the growing, and mind that I have grown MANY I have never had a problem with blistering. So my simple answer is no it shouldn't happen*. The only time I have heard this *could* happen is by raped ripening. But I don;t know how that is done, if even possible.

*Not implying it will not happen